# Does Redis have persistence capability for selected keys/data?

Tags: redis

I am aware of Redis having persistence option of RDB and AOF which to me is more or less  entire redis cache store back-up.

Do we have persistence capability only for selected keys ?
One solution is to have long TTL but that would still be lost in case of a power failure or crash.

My requirement is not to persist entire data from redis but selected keys.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 8):

No - Redis' data persistence applies to the entire dataset that the server manages, meaning all keys in all numbered databases.

If you want to persist just a bunch of keys, provision a separate Redis database for these and configure its persistency (AOF and/or RDB) accordingly.

Comment: Do we have multiple database running under one redis server instance similar to Mongo Collection? It would be difficult to partition data for few keys on one persistent redis db and rest on default redis db. Will the connection string change?

Comment: To clarify - separate means a different connection for each type of key. Difficult as it may be, there is no other way to do it